# Save with a different name if the file already exists in directory

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know where I am wrong with this code.

```
If Dir(FILE_PATH & personList(i, 1) & FILE_EXT) <> "" Then
    .SaveAs2 FILE_PATH & "1" & personList(i, 1) & FILE_EXT
    .Close
Else
    .SaveAs2 FILE_PATH & personList(i, 1) & FILE_EXT
    .Close
End If
```

Everything just works fine, but when I encounter the same value in a column (for example: John Doe, John Doe), the program overwrites the first John Doe file.

Comment: put a break point on the save part. add a watch on the person(i,1). when you are expecting it to overwright see what is happening and see what ?FILE_PATH & personList(i, 1) & FILE_EXT equates to. There should be nothing wrong with your code

Comment: `.SaveAs2` isn't available in Excel VBA - are you using this in another program? Or are you working with word documents?

Comment: I am working with word documents, through bookmarks I am inserting some values from cells into a word docs..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a function you can use to retrieve a unique file name for any given path. It will suffix the filename with a `" - n"`, where `n` is a sequential number.

```
Function GetNextAvailableName(ByVal strPath As String) As String

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        Dim strFolder As String, strBaseName As String, strExt As String, i As Long
        strFolder   = .GetParentFolderName(strPath)
        strBaseName = .GetBaseName(strPath)
        strExt      = .GetExtensionName(strPath)

        Do While .FileExists(strPath)
            i = i + 1
            strPath = .BuildPath(strFolder, strBaseName & " - " & i & "." & strExt)
        Loop

    End With

    GetNextAvailableName = strPath

End Function
```

Assuming the file `c:\path\to\file.ext` exists, the following call:

```
Debug.Print GetNextAvailableName("c:\path\to\file.ext")
```

would print:

```
c:\path\to\file - 1.ext
```

Comment: I will try this today, and will let you know the result. tnx

Comment: `.SaveAs2 GetNextAvailableName ("D:\template.doc")`  is this ok?

Comment: Works great!  I added `i = 2` before the `Do While` loop so that I don't end up with "MyFile - 1.ext".  In my mind, it's confusing to have "MyFile.ext" and "MyFile - 1.ext".  Thanks @Bond!

Answer (score 1):

I've had this function hanging around for an age - not sure where I got it from though.  It will pause if the file name hasn't got an extension, or there's more than 100 files with the same base name:

```
Sub test()

    Debug.Print GenerateUniqueName("S:\Bartrup-CookD\New Folder\Book1.xlsm")

End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------------------
' GenerateUniqueName
'
'   Generates a file name that doesn't exist by appending a number
'   in between the base name and the extension.
'   Example: GenerateUniqueName("c:\folder\file.ext") = "c:\folder\file4.ext"
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
Function GenerateUniqueName(FullFileName As String, Optional fAlwaysAddNumber As Boolean) As String

    Dim objFSO As Object: Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Not objFSO.FileExists(FullFileName) And Not fAlwaysAddNumber Then
        GenerateUniqueName = FullFileName
    Else
        Dim strExt As String
        Dim strNonExt As String
        Dim strNewName As String
        Dim i As Integer
        strExt = objFSO.GetExtensionName(FullFileName)
        Debug.Assert strExt <> ""
        strNonExt = objFSO.BuildPath(objFSO.GetParentFolderName(FullFileName), objFSO.GetBaseName(FullFileName))
        Do
            Debug.Assert i < 100
            i = i + 1
            strNewName = strNonExt & i & "." & strExt

        Loop While objFSO.FileExists(strNewName)
        GenerateUniqueName = strNewName
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If FileLen(FILE_PATH & personList(i, 1) & FILE_EXT) > 0 Then
    '// File Exists, change name accordingly.
Else
    '// File doesn't exist, save as is.
End If
```

Comment: why did you pu &"1"&?

Comment: @MacroMan Thanks for the laugh!

Comment: @Ram it's commented, which bit would you like explaining?

Comment: @This answer came up in the low quality posts review queue so dropped a comment to expand the answer.

Comment: @Ram ah, ok. I think the comments explain so I'll leave it as it is.

Comment: Yeah, but I dont get it why "1". I put "1" for .SaveAs2 line of code. `FILE_PATH & "1" & personList(i, 1) & FILE_EXT` isnt right path, the right path is `FILE_PATH & personList(i, 1) & FILE_EXT`  Thanks!

Comment: @Stefan89BEG Okay, I've edited above - does this solve the issue?

Comment: @Macro Man, i will try this in 20 minutes, and we will know if it works. tnx on your effort, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You meant on this: `        If FileLen(FILE_PATH & personList(i, 1) & FILE_EXT) > 0 Then
    .SaveAs2 FILE_PATH & personList(i, 1) & "1" & FILE_EXT
                   .Close '// File Exists, change name accordingly.
Else
   .SaveAs2 FILE_PATH & personList(i, 1) & FILE_EXT
                          .Close '// File doesn't exist, save as is.
End If`   it doesnt working..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function for creating unique filepath [(taken from http://mielk.pl/)](http://mielk.pl/en/download/code/system/uniqueFilePath.php):

```
Public Function uniqueFilePath(filepath As String) As String
    Const METHOD_NAME As String = "uniqueFilePath"
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Static objFSO As Object                 '(Late binding that allows to use the function, even if
                                            'Microsoft Scripting Runtime library is not loaded)
    Dim strFileExtension As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strParentFolder As String
    Dim strTempFilePath As String
    Dim intCounter As Integer
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    'Create FileSystemObject instance if it hasn't been created yet. ------------------------------------|
    If objFSO Is Nothing Then                                                                           '|
        Set objFSO = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")                                     '|
    End If                                                                                              '|
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|


    With objFSO

        'Checks if the file already exists. -------------------------------------------------------------|
        If .fileExists(filepath) Then                                                                   '|
                                                                                                        '|
            'If the given filepath already exists, function transforms its name by                      '|
            'appending the number in brackets.                                                          '|
            strParentFolder = .GetParentFolderName(filepath)                                            '|
            If Not VBA.right$(strParentFolder, 1) = "\" Then strParentFolder = strParentFolder & "\"    '|
            strFileName = .GetBaseName(filepath)                                                        '|
            strFileExtension = "." & .GetExtensionName(filepath)                                        '|
                                                                                                        '|
            '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|      '|
            Do                                                                                  '|      '|
                intCounter = intCounter + 1                                                     '|      '|
                strTempFilePath = strParentFolder & strFileName & _
                                                " (" & intCounter & ")" & strFileExtension      '|      '|
            Loop While .fileExists(strTempFilePath)                                             '|      '|
            '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|      '|
                                                                                                        '|
            uniqueFilePath = strTempFilePath                                                            '|
                                                                                                        '|
        Else                                                                                            '|
                                                                                                        '|
            'Specified filepath is unique in the file system and is returned in its original form.      '|
            uniqueFilePath = filepath                                                                   '|
                                                                                                        '|
        End If                                                                                          '|
        '-------- [If .FileExists(filepath) Then] -------------------------------------------------------|

    End With


End Function
```

In order to make the code below work properly you must paste it in your code.

If the filepath you give as a parameter already exists, **function returns the same filepath with the number in bracket appended**, i.e. if file "C:\file.xlsx" already exists function returns "C:\file (1).xlsx".

If this file doesn't exists the **function returns the original filepath** without any changes.

Replace all the code you pasted in your question with the below:

```
Dim filepath As String

filepath = uniqueFilePath(FILE_PATH & personList(i, 1) & FILE_EXT)
Call .SaveAs(filepath)
Call .Close
```

Comment: mielk, I've copied function in the module, below the main sub, when I hit f5, no error, but no files either in the path...

Comment: What happens if you run it in the Immediate window and give some existing path as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I use something very similar, for upissuing documents. Could see if you can change this to your needs

```
Rechecker:
Filename = Sheets("Word_Front").Range("N142").Value
If Not (Update_Only) Then
    If Dir(sDocPath & Filename & Cert & ".docx") <> "" Then
        iret = MsgBox("Existing file found with this filename, Answer YES to up-issue the file. Please note there is no further warning and NO to overwrite the file.", vbYesNo)
        If iret = 6 Then
            Sheets("Word_Front").Range("Q7").Value = Sheets("Word_Front").Range("Q7").Value + 1
            GoTo Rechecker
        Else
            oDoc.SaveAs sDocPath & Filename & Cert & ".docx", 16
        End If
    Else
        oDoc.SaveAs sDocPath & Filename & Cert & ".docx", 16
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of these are very long answers for what seems like a pretty simple issue. Most reference a FileSystemObject; which I notice you have not referenced.

My solution would be to use `WHILE` instead of `IF`

```
While Dir(FILE_PATH & personList(i, 1) & FILE_EXT) <> ""
    i = i + 1
Wend
.SaveAs2 FILE_PATH & i & "1" & personList(i, 1) & FILE_EXT
.Close
```

This preserves the "1" you have in your initial code when the file does not already exists. It also means that you can have a few thousand duplicate names in your list since the first John Doe's file would be named "11John Doe", the second would be "21John Doe", then "31John Doe", etc. Much lighter code that doesn't start implementing new libraries.