# duplicate file checking when exporting

Tags: excel, vba

can someone tell me what im doing wrong, I am trying to export a file and if the file exists to add duplicate onto the end of it,  I cant seem to get it to work

```
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim MyDate As String
Dim megalist As String
Dim FileCopy As String
Dim copy As String

copy = " Duplicate"
FilePath = "Q:\RADIOLOGY\ADMINISTRATION\DATA\CT DISTRIBUTION\PAY ROLL\"
MyDate = Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY")
megalist = " Megalist"

FileName = FilePath & MyDate & megalist
FileCopy = FilePath & MyDate & megalist & copy
If Dir(FilePath) <> MyDate & Report Then
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=FileName
Else
     ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=FileCopy
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If Dir(FilePath) <> MyDate & Report Then 

should have been

If Dir(FilePath) <> MyDate & megalist Then

Comment: assume your code works and what if the duplicate file also exists?

Comment: Well if I it was possible to just add an ever increasing number that would be preferable

Answer (score 1):

See below answer to generate your FileName.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31706252/1684486

and then simply use `ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=FileName`

**EDiT**
in your case:

```
FilePath = "Q:\RADIOLOGY\ADMINISTRATION\DATA\CT DISTRIBUTION\PAY ROLL\"
MyDate = Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY")
megalist = " Megalist"

FileName = GetNextAvailableName(FilePath & MyDate & megalist)
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=FileName
```

of course you need to copy the `GetNextAvailableName` function from that answer to a public module in your project.

Comment: im sorry for being slow, im not sure how to incorporate this into mine, im very new at this